# Invalid month and date allowed in spring webflow

Tags: java, spring-webflow

When I try to enter date format 40/40/2017, spring webflow converts it into fast time and converts it to a valid date. This avoids any error thrown by the validator. Is there any way I can make this invalid without converting the variable to string?

Comment: Refer this link for more help regarding this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156651/spring-webflow-and-type-conversion-for-date-formatting

Answer (score 1):

As there are several approach in `Spring MVC` to resolve these issues like use `initBinder`.First pass this Date value to initBinder so that it will throw an error(at the time of validation) by the validator.
Try this it may be helpfull

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new 
                                       CustomDateEditor(dateFormat,true));
}
```

Comment: And you probably want to `dateFormat.setLenient(false)` in your binder, so that values like month=40 are *not* accepted.